# How do I extract elevation data from a DEM using points I have in a CSV?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, csv, elevation

So I have a CSV with a lot of fields. The first 3 fields are the ID, longitude, and latitude. I have already converted to decimal degrees, and said to display XY data. (Is there something else I need to do before I can use these points?)

Now I need to know what Spatial Analyst tool to use to extract the elevation for each point, and how to use that tool. I tried extract by mask and Extract Multi Values to points, but neither worked.

Extract by mask left me with just one elevation for all 531 points. Extract by multi values failed to execute.

What do you think? I'm very inexperienced, so a step-by-step guide would help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

After displaying your points as X,Y data you need to save the layer to a spatial format that is useable in the ArcMap geoprocessing tools. You can right-click on the points in your table of contents and choose to export them to a shapefile (or other format). Once this has completed, choose the option to add the new layer to the map. Use this new layer as input into the Extract Values to Points tool.

You can view information about a failed run of a geoprocessing tool by clicking on **Geoprocessing --> Results** and viewing the output messages.